# Programmatically triggering System.Windows.Forms.Control event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Let's say I have a Checkbox control:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.CheckedChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
};
```

How can I programmatically trigger this event?

I can do

```
cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
```

but that is ugly and will trigger it twice...

Answer (score 4):

I would refactor your code:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.CheckedChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMessageBox();
};

private void ShowMessageBox()
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Now, call `ShowMessageBox` instead of trying to simulate events. Pass along whatever information you need from the event to the method, in case it needs more to carry out its task:

```
cb.CheckedChanged += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowMessageBox(cb.Checked);
};

private void ShowMessageBox(bool checkedValue)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The box was {0}checked", 
        checkedValue ? "" : "un"));
}
```

Comment: And if there is more than one event attached to CheckedChanged? I need to simulate a real event...

Comment: @Anders: I don't know of any way to do that on a `CheckBox`. For regular buttons there is the [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method, but there is nothing like that on `CheckBox` (that I know of).

Comment: @Anders: Derive your own class from Checkbox and add a public method that calls OnCheckChanged().  Only way.  It is smelly, other code won't count on the Checked property not actually changing, it might not even check the value.

Comment: @Hans: (+1) Yeah, that is pretty smelly and I was really hoping for a more general solution.